# Correlation between raster pixels within each polygon

Tags: qgis, raster, r, correlation

I have two raster layers with the same extent, CRS, and resolution, and a shapefile consisting of a number of polygons. I would like to calculate the Pearson correlation between the two rasters within each polygon, and write such values within a new attribute for all the polygons.

I work with QGIS and R.

Comment: You can convert the polygon to Raster then make the correlation using ERDAS Imagine (I can do this on ERDAS but on QGIS i can't because i'm a beginner of this software )
[Jamal chaaouan](https://www.geojamal.com) [GIS English](https://www.gisenglish.com)

Comment: Use raster::extract to retrieve the raster values for each polygon and then use apply or mapply to calculate the correlations.

Answer (score -1):

I find this answer: 
Considering that all layers are identical in extent and resolution you could stack them all together and compute correlation among stacked objects simply with:

```
library(raster) 
myfolder <- 'D:/myfolder' 
r_path <- file.path(myfolder, grep(".tif$", 
list.files(file.path(myfolder), 
all.files = F), 
ignore.case = TRUE, value = TRUE)) 
mystack <- raster::stack(r_path) 
raster::layerStats(mystack, 'pearson')
```

done!

Comment: But this does not consider the polygons, at all. It just produces a global figure.

Answer (score -1):

I am testing this solution. Please correct me if you spot mistakes.

```
summaryshapes<-list.files(pattern = "\\.shp$")

shapes<-lapply(summaryshapes, readogr)

crop_masked<-list()

crop_masked[i]<-for (i in 1:length(shapes)) {
  raster1_cropped <- crop(raster1, extent(shapes[[i]]))
  raster2_cropped<- crop(raster2, extent(shapes[[i]]))
}

correlationfunction<-function(X){
b[X] <- stack(raster1_cropped[X],raster2_cropped[X])
corre[X] <- sampleRegular(b[X], 100000)
cor.test(corre[X][,1], corre[,2])
}

corr<-lapply(names(shapes), correlationfunction)
```